# Не получается передать данные о дате из textField в параметр типа Date. Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Tags: строки, swift, дата, datepicker, преобразование-типов

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне преобразовать данные типа String в параметр типа Date?
У меня такая проблема: есть структура у которой один из параметров имеет тип "Date":

```
struct Item {
var date: Date

init(date: Date) {
    self.date = date
}
}
```

Чтобы передать в этот параметр значение при инициализации я по туториал создал textField, при нажатии на которое через inputView появляется DatePicker и дает возможность поместить выбранную дату в textField:
(Тут все работает, данные отображаются в текстовом поле исправно)

```
@IBOutlet weak var expenceDateTextField: UITextField!
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            createDatePicker()
}

func createDatePicker() {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))

    expenceDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    expenceDateTextField.inputView = datePicker
}
@objc func donePressed() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    
    expenceDateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)   
}
```

Тут все отлично работает, дата отображается в текстовом поле в удовлетворительном виде и наступает сложность, которую я пока решить не смог: как передать .text из текстового поля в параметр типа  Date?

```
@IBAction func saveCklicked(_ sender: UIButton) {      
    let date = expenceDateTextField.text!
     
    let newItem = Item(date: date)
```

На этом месте компилятор мне говорит, что не может конвертировать значение типа String в аргумент типа Date. (Напротив последней строчки)

Ничего умнее чем это я пока не придумал:

```
    let date = Date(expenceDateTextField.text!)
```

На что получил ошибку "No exact matches in call to initializer "

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне преобразовать данные типа String в параметр типа Date?

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы не передаёте `datePicker.date` там, где это вам нужно? Попробуйте так, если это не решит проблему, то: `UITextField` действительно имеет строку, в методе `donePressed` из типа `Date` вы переходите в `String`, в обратную сторону можно перейти, указав формат для DateFormatter'а такой же, как вы указали выше и затем вызвав: `formatter.date(from:)`

Пример кода:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .none

let string: String = formatter.string(from: Date())
print(string)
let date: Date = formatter.date(from: string)
if let date = date {
    print(date)
}
```